# Angular checkout.com not loading frames

Tags: angular

I have used below angular library for integration
https://github.com/checkout/frames-angular

It's not loading frames for input fields. No errors.
But it's working fine in newly created project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use *ngIf, it will work. Don't use components, use div and their class